# Duplicate module name: create-react-context. Declaration with same name across different files

Tags: react-native, jsx, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I have the following `React Native` project:

https://github.com/napolev/react-native-paper

which I cloned from their official `GitHub` repository (there are no changes at all so far).

To install it and run it I did:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/napolev/react-native-paper
$ cd react-native-paper
$ npm i
$ cd example
$ npm i
$ expo start
```

After I get the `QR` code on the terminal I scan it with either: my `Android` or `iOS` smartphone and just after that I get on the terminal the following error:

```
$ expo start
[00:53:27] Starting project at D:\react-native-paper\example
[00:53:28] Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
[00:53:36] Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
[00:53:38] Tunnel ready.
[00:53:38] Your app is running at exp://192.168.1.194:19000
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
[00:53:52] jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
[00:53:52]   Duplicate module name: create-react-context
[00:53:52]   Paths: D:\react-native-paper\example\node_modules\react-navigation\node_modules\create-react-context\package.json collides with D:\react-native-paper\example\node_modules\create-react-context\package.json
[00:53:52]
[00:53:52] This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
[00:53:52] (node:9828) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
[00:53:52]   Duplicate module name: create-react-context
[00:53:52]   Paths: D:\react-native-paper\example\node_modules\react-navigation\node_modules\create-react-context\package.json collides with D:\react-native-paper\example\node_modules\create-react-context\package.json
[00:53:52]
[00:53:52] This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
[00:53:52]     at setModule (D:\react-native-paper\example\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:462:17)
[00:53:52]     at workerReply (D:\react-native-paper\example\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:512:9)
[00:53:52]     at <anonymous>
[00:53:52]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
[00:53:52] (node:9828) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
[00:53:52] (node:9828) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Also, on my both mobiles I get the following:

[image]

I don't understand why I don't get it to work when it was supposed that whatever the authors of that repository have in there is ready for install and run right away.

Any idea on how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This project uses `yarn` as a dependency manager, and is using specific features for selective version resolutions for its dependencies. see `package.json`:

```
"resolutions": {
    "**/create-react-context": "0.2.3", 
    ...
```

Clear your `node_modules` and reinstall using `yarn`.

Comment: I did:`$ yarn install` but didn't work either. Here is my experiment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54157104