# Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault from index.js

Tags: node.js, react-native, babeljs, expo, yarnpkg

I just cloned this repository: [react-native-paper](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper)

but when I run on the root directory:

```
$ yarn install
```

I get the following warnings:

```
D:\react-native-paper (master) (react-native-paper@2.4.0)
λ yarn install
yarn install v1.13.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning Resolution field "babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0" is incompatible with requested version "babel-core@^6.26.0"
warning Resolution field "babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0" is incompatible with requested version "babel-core@^6.26.0"
warning Resolution field "babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0" is incompatible with requested version "babel-core@^6.0.0"
warning Resolution field "babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0" is incompatible with requested version "babel-core@^6.0.0"
warning Resolution field "babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0" is incompatible with requested version "babel-core@^6.7.2"
```

Then, when I do:

```
$ cd example
$ yarn install
```

I get the following output with more warnings:

```
yarn install v1.13.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning Resolution field "create-react-context@0.2.3" is incompatible with requested version "create-react-context@0.2.2"
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.5.0: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.5.0" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > create-react-context@0.2.3" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.0.0".
warning " > @expo/vector-icons@8.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "expo-font@^1.0.0".
warning "expo > react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.10" has incorrect peer dependency "react@16.0.0-alpha.6".
warning "expo > react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.10" has incorrect peer dependency "react-native@^0.44.1".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators@7.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators > @babel/plugin-syntax-decorators@7.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0". warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-classes@7.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-destructuring@7.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator@7.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-for-of@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-function-name@7.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-literals@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-object-assign@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-parameters@7.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0". warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-spread@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-template-literals@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties > @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator > @babel/plugin-syntax-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread > @babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding > @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-catch-binding@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining > @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types > @babel/plugin-syntax-flow@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-typescript > @babel/plugin-syntax-typescript@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
```

I pay specially attention to the above warnings because when I try to run the application with (inside directory: `/example`):

```
$ yarn start
```

I get the following output on the terminal:

```
There is a new version of expo-cli available (2.6.14).
You are currently using expo-cli 2.3.8
Run `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the latest version
[23:26:13] Starting project at D:\react-native-paper\example
[23:26:23] Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
[23:26:23] Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
[23:27:19] Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
[23:27:32] Successfully ran `adb reverse`. Localhost URLs should work on the connected Android device.
[23:27:36] Tunnel ready.

  exp://192.168.1.194:19000

  [QR CODE HERE]

  To run the app with live reloading, choose one of:
  • Sign in as @napolev in Expo Client on Android or iOS. Your projects will automatically appear in the "Projects" tab.
  • Scan the QR code above with the Expo app (Android) or the Camera app (iOS).
  • Press a for Android emulator.
  • Press e to send a link to your phone with email/SMS.

Press ? to show a list of all available commands.
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
[23:28:51] Unable to resolve "@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault" from "..\src\index.js"
Building JavaScript bundle [=================================================================================================== ] 99%
```

and also I get the following output on the mobile:

`Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault from index.js`

as you can see on the image below:

[image]

Any idea on how to make this application run on the mobile?

Thanks!

Comment: try updating expo to latest version (currently v2.6.14)

Answer (score -1):

Please try to execute

```
yarn add @babel/runtime
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.